# Apply custom aggregation on Collectors.groupingBy

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

I've a `Map<A,B> AvsB` where `A` and `B` are,

```
class A {
    Long id;
    AggregationType aggr;
}

class B {
    Long value;
}
```

where AggregationType is an enum that contains (`SUM, AVG, MIN, MAX`).

I created a stream from the entry set and I want to group this list of entries by A.id and apply custom aggregation on B.value from the resulting downstream.

```
Map<Long, Double> aggregatedMap = AvsB.entrySet().stream().groupingBy(
    entry -> entry.getKey().getId(),
    Collectors.summingDouble(entry-> (double)entry.getValue().getValue())
)
```

I'm able to solve this for a single aggregation, like sum in this case, but I don't know how to solve it with the aggregation being fetched from A (i.e.) I need a switch case for each enum, so for example, for `AVG` I'll use `Collectors.averagingDouble` instead of `Collectors.summingDouble`.
Can someone please help? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are 2 problems: firstly, these collectors do not have the same return type. Even if you use a *DoubleStream* or a *LongStream* you'll get closer, but you still won't have exactly the same return type. Therefore, we'll need to do a bit of extra work to make them return the same thing. For instance, this can be one option:

```
private double collectValues(AggregatorType agg, List<Long> values) {
    DoubleStream stream = values.stream().mapToDouble(x -> x + 0.0d);
    return switch (agg) {
        case AVG -> stream.average().orElseThrow();
        case SUM -> stream.sum();
        case MAX -> stream.max().orElseThrow();
        case MIN -> stream.min().orElseThrow();
        default -> throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    };
}
```

The second problem will be that we can not easily use different collectors for the elements of the same stream. Therefore, you need to do it a bit differently - for example, you can do it in 2 steps. Initially, collect all the B.value by the *Aggegator.Type* :

```
public Map<AggregatorType, Double> aggregate(Map<A, B> fields) {
    Map<AggregatorType, List<Long>> valuesByType = fields.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            entry -> entry.getKey().type(),
            Collectors.mapping(
                entry -> entry.getValue().value(),
                Collectors.toList())
        ));
    // return valuesByType.stream()...
}
```

And then, collect each *List* using the function from the first code snippet:

```
 return valuesByType.entrySet()
     .stream()
     .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            entry -> entry.getKey(),
            entry -> collectValues(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue())
     ));
```

Here is the full story:

```
@Test
void test() {
    //given
    Map<A, B> values = Map.of(
        new A(1L, AggregatorType.AVG), new B(10L),
        new A(2L, AggregatorType.AVG), new B(20L),
        new A(3L, AggregatorType.SUM), new B(30L),
        new A(4L, AggregatorType.SUM), new B(40L),
        new A(5L, AggregatorType.MAX), new B(50L),
        new A(6L, AggregatorType.MAX), new B(60L),
        new A(7L, AggregatorType.MIN), new B(70L),
        new A(8L, AggregatorType.MIN), new B(80L)
    );

    // when
    Map<AggregatorType, Double> result = aggregate(values);

    //then
    assertThat(result).isEqualTo(Map.of(
        AggregatorType.AVG, 15d,
        AggregatorType.SUM, 70d,
        AggregatorType.MAX, 60d,
        AggregatorType.MIN, 70d
    ));
}

public Map<AggregatorType, Double> aggregate(Map<A, B> fields) {
    Map<AggregatorType, List<Long>> valuesByType = fields.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            entry -> entry.getKey().type(),
            Collectors.mapping(
                entry -> entry.getValue().value(),
                Collectors.toList())
        ));
    return valuesByType.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            entry -> entry.getKey(),
            entry -> collectValues(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue())
        ));
}

private double collectValues(AggregatorType aggregator, List<Long> values) {
    DoubleStream stream = values.stream().mapToDouble(x -> x + 0.0d);
    return switch (aggregator) {
        case AVG -> stream.average().orElseThrow();
        case SUM -> stream.sum();
        case MAX -> stream.max().orElseThrow();
        case MIN -> stream.min().orElseThrow();
        default -> throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    };
}
```

if you want to see how I did it, step-by-step, feel free to read through this article: https://medium.com/javarevisited/polymorphic-stream-collector-in-java-44f9008bf043?sk=b92590ad1c65a3731746404dbd53b0f7